# Euler's equations 1d for pipe, Inlet boundary conditions

Tags: boundary-conditions, finite-volume, fluid-dynamics

$\def\rmin{{\mathrm{in}}}$
$\def\l{\left}\def\r{\right}$
$\def\tagl#1{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$ 
I am using the one-dimensional finite volume method to calculate the air flow in some tube.
For subsonic flow one can predefine two quantities at the inlet.

The inlet is a wide opening to the ambient.
The overall system deeply inside the tube is a bit more complicated. But, this does not really matter here. The system is described in some PhD and I am coding along the lines of this PhD. The author assumes isentropic flow at the inlet.

For the inlet pressure $p_\rmin$ he gave the formula
\begin{align}
  p_\rmin + \frac{\gamma-1}\gamma\rho_0 \l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac1\gamma}\frac{u_\rmin^2}2&= p_0
  \tagl{A20amb}
\end{align}
with the ambient pressure $p_0=10^5 \rm Pa$, the ambient air density $\rho_0=1.23\rm \frac{kg}{m^3}$ and the given inlet velocity $u_\rmin$ .
After solving this equation for $p_\rmin$ one can also determine the inlet density $\rho_\rmin$.

**Pittyingly, I do not get this equation.**

He motivated \eqref{A20amb} through the ideal gas law
\begin{align}
  p=\rho(c_p-c_v)T,
  \tagl{A1amb}
\end{align}
the assumption of isentropic state transition
\begin{align}
  \frac{p_\rmin}{p_0} = \l(\frac{\rho_\rmin}{\rho_0}\r)^\gamma
  \tagl{A3amb}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
  \gamma := \frac{c_p}{c_v},
  \tagl{A2}
\end{align}
and the energy balance
\begin{align}
  c_p T_0 = c_pT_\rmin + \frac12 u_\rmin^2
  \tagl{A5amb}
\end{align}
with the ambient temperature $T_0$.

Substitution of $T=\frac{p}{(c_p-c_v)\rho}$ from \eqref{A1amb} into \eqref{A5amb} delivers with $\rho_\rmin = \rho_0\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{1/\gamma}$ from \eqref{A3amb}  the equation
\begin{align}
  c_p\frac{p_0}{(c_p-c_v)\rho_0} = c_p\frac{p_\rmin}{(c_p-c_v)\rho_0\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{1/\gamma}} +\frac12 u_\rmin^2
\end{align}
which can be transformed into
\begin{align}
  1 &= \l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac{\gamma-1}\gamma} + (\gamma-1) \frac{\rho_0}{\gamma p_0}\cdot\frac{u_\rmin^2}2\\
  1 &= \l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac{\gamma-1}\gamma} + \frac{\gamma-1}2\l(\frac{u_\rmin}{c_0}\r)^2
  \tagl{p0}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
c_0=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma p_0}{\rho_0}}
\tagl{speedOfSound}
\end{align}
is the speed of sound in the ambient.

This formula can be resolved for the inlet pressure:
\begin{align}
  p_\rmin &= p_0 \l(1-\frac{\gamma-1}2\l(\frac{u_\rmin}{c_0}\r)^2\r)^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}}
\tagl{solution}
\end{align}
<strike>I did not check whether \eqref{solution} is equivalent to \eqref{A20amb}. But, I do not think so because then the author would have used the explicite form \eqref{solution} to calculate $p_\rmin$.</strike> EDIT: I did check for differences. See below.

**What am I missing??**
Did I miss-interprete the assumptions?

---

Note that also \eqref{A20amb} can be re-formulated with the help of $c_0$:
\begin{align}
\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r) + \frac{\gamma-1}2 \l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac1\gamma}\l(\frac{u_\rmin}{c_0}\r)^2 = 1
\tagl{A20mod}
\end{align}
If one divides by $\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac1\gamma}$ one nicely recognizes the difference between \eqref{A20amb} and \eqref{p0}:
\begin{align}
\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{\frac{\gamma-1}\gamma} + \frac{\gamma-1}2\l(\frac{u_\rmin}{c_0}\r)^2 = \l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{-\frac1\gamma}
\tagl{A20mod2}
\end{align}
Instead of the 1 on the left-hand side of \eqref{p0} the formula from the PhD-thesis has a $\l(\frac{p_\rmin}{p_0}\r)^{-\frac1\gamma}$.

Comment: Sorry, in the equation-references worked in the preview but they do not work in the post. I try to improve them...

Comment: Possibly just a typo in your work, but $R=c_p-c_v$, not $c_v-c_p$ as you have above. Looks like you (or the author) carried that mistake through.

Comment: @Aurelius Thank you very much. I corrected this. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I lack the time to dig into it at the moment (sorry), but any chance sections 2.9, 2.10, and 2.11 from [Liepmann and Roshko](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486419630) (available in the linked Amazon preview) can help resolve your question?  The exposition and derivations in that book are quite good.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had a look into the book. It looks good. Nevertheless, I try to attract attention with a bounty. Maybe, someone can point out the origin of the discrepancy.